# If a human transforms to a new cosm might they change race?

Tags: torg

In classic *Torg* as well as the new *Torg Eternity*, the rules for disconnection and transformation seem clear; in certain circumstances a character from one cosm might lose their connection to that cosm and become a native of another cosm. This reconnection is referred to as "transformation," and it includes a number of possible effects, including at least minor physical changes to the new cosm.  For instance, a human from Core Earth transforming to the Cyberpapacy might see their existing medical implants become true cyberware.

Do any current or previous *Torg* materials make reference to the possibility that a Core Earth human transforming to the Living Land or Aysle might become a member of one of those cosms' native races, such as the edeinos, elves or trolls?

As a GM I think it's not unreasonable but I'd like to know whether such a thing is considered possible in the existing source material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least as far as Torg Eternity, there is nothing that says the races change for anyone. Since the races aren't just normal people turned into other races in any reality, but are born that race to their native reality.  Otherwise skills/perks will change to meet the new reality.

> Races found only in other cosms, including
>   edeinos, elves, and dwarves, don’t change race if
>   they transform, but they may become confused or
>   crazed by the process. Elves are especially hard
>   hit if the reality they conform to doesn’t have a
>   high enough Magic Axiom to support them. Such
>   elves don’t die, but the Magical Affinity ability is
>   always in effect.
>   Transformed Ords often gain new, equivalent
>   skills to fit their reality. A college teacher could
>   suddenly find himself casting magic spells in Aysle,
>   or a mechanic could operate a cyberware chop shop
>   in the Cyberpapacy.
>   Ords remember their old lives, but they have a
>   hard time concentrating on contradictory concepts.
>   An Ord who transforms to the Living Land
>   remembers that automobiles exist and that they
>   get you from one place to another, but couldn’t
>   explain how they work or drive one.